# Lost Cycles Render Settings

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials, lighting, color

I was working in the Eevee renderer and when I switched over onto cycles I noticed that all the settings tabs that would have been under 'scene' were gone. Not only this but I couldn't change the material settings for any object which I usually would have done in the materials sidebar. I am able to use the materials side-bar when in Eevee. The only way I can change the materials is by doing it in the shader editor.

This is really odd and hasn't happened to me before, so I was wondering if anyone has come across the problem before and has any idea of how to fix this predicament I am in. Below are some images that illustrate the problem I am having.

https://i.imgur.com/Hm4z8Ne.png https://i.imgur.com/bKXKvOi.png https://i.imgur.com/WRkmJVx.png

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you accidentally filtered the Cycles add-on in the current workspace (Sidebar (N) > Tool > Workspace > Filter Add-ons)?

Comment: Yes I must have done. Thanks for the help!